# $z = x^2+2y^2, $ and $x=r\cos(\theta), y=r\sin(\theta)$ What is ($\frac{\partial z}{\partial \theta})_y =?$

Tags: partial-derivative

Suppose $z = x^2+2y^2, $ and

$x=r\cos(\theta), y=r\sin(\theta)$

What is ($\frac{\partial z}{\partial \theta})_y =?$ This is the partial derivative of $z$ with respect to $\theta$, holding $y$ constant.

Here is my thought process.  We need to transform $z$ to only use $\theta$ and $y$ without $x$.

So $z = x^2 +y^2 + y^2 = r^2+y^2$

We know $ y=r\sin(\theta)$, so $ y^2=r^2\sin^2(\theta)$.  Then we can solve for $r^2$.

$r^2 = \frac{y^2}{\sin^2\theta}$

Finally, plug $r^2$  into $z$

$z = \frac{y^2}{\sin^2\theta} + y^2 = y^2(\frac{1}{\sin^2\theta}+1) $

At this point $z$ is in terms of only $\theta$ and $y$.  We are ready to take ($\frac{\partial z}{\partial \theta})_y $.

($\frac{\partial z}{\partial \theta})_y = -2y^2 \cot(\theta) \csc^2(\theta)$.

However, this is the wrong answer. The solution is $-2r^2 \cot \theta$.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is equivalent to the correct one. Note that $y=r\sin(\theta)$ so the $\csc^2(\theta)$ should vanish

Comment: damn, i should have caught that